# I would like to know if I can create an ar experience using facebook that will play entire songs and videos?

Tags: facebook, augmented-reality

I'm new to the Facebook AR studio and wanted to know if I can add entire songs and videos to a marker. And if that marker can be a simple logo or graphic.

Answer (score 0):

AR Studio does not allow markers at this moment. As far as I know there is no information about when this feature will be available.

Regarding playing songs and videos, the only limitation I think you will find is the size of the effect. Facebook asks developers to limit the effect file size to 2MB.